# How can I make a description of some sort appear if a certain attribute is selected on the product detail page

Tags: prestashop

I am new to prestashop but I am trying to make a tiny description appear after someone clicks on a certain select type attribute.

I have tried to do an if statement to select the one attribute that I want but I am doing this action to all the atributes in the same group.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.